# Are measurable performance gains possible from using VC++'s __assume?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++, compiler-optimization

Are measurable performance gains possible from using VC++'s `__assume`? If so, please post proof with code and benchmarks in your answer.

The sparse MSDN article on __assume: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b3fsfxw(v=vs.100).aspx

Mentioned in the article is the use of `__assume(0)` to make `switch` statements faster by `__assume(0)`ing the `default` case. I measured no performance increase from using `__assume(0)` in that way:

```
void NoAssumeSwitchStatement(int i)
{
    switch (i)
    {
    case 0:
        vector<int>();
        break;
    case 1:
        vector<int>();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void AssumeSwitchStatement(int i)
{
    switch (i)
    {
    case 0:
        vector<int>();
        break;
    case 1:
        vector<int>();
        break;
    default:
        __assume(0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const int Iterations = 1000000;
    LARGE_INTEGER start, middle, end;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
    for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; ++i)
    {
        NoAssumeSwitchStatement(i % 2);         
    }
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&middle);
    for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; ++i)
    {
        AssumeSwitchStatement(i % 2);
    }
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
    LARGE_INTEGER cpuFrequency;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&cpuFrequency);
    cout << "NoAssumeSwitchStatement: " << (((double)(middle.QuadPart - start.QuadPart)) * 1000) / (double)cpuFrequency.QuadPart << "ms" << endl;
    cout << "  AssumeSwitchStatement: " << (((double)(end.QuadPart - middle.QuadPart)) * 1000) / (double)cpuFrequency.QuadPart << "ms" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Rounded console output, 1000000 iterations:

NoAssumeSwitchStatement: 46ms
AssumeSwitchStatement: 46ms

Comment: Your example seems too trivial. If you look at the assembler output, it will be the same. NOP.

Comment: IMO it would have made more sense when the compiler knows the default case cannot be reached when you just leave it out instead of a dull assume instruction...

Comment: `__assume` is a hint to the optimizer, most useful at higher levels of optimization. (i.e. going beyound register allocation and CSE). At those levels, this example can be expected to fully inlined; i.e. both your 2 function calls and all 4 temporaries created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems it does make a little difference if you set the right compiler switches...

Three runs follow.  No optimizations, opt for speed and opt for size.

This run has no optimizations

```
C:\temp\code>cl /EHsc /FAscu assume.cpp
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86

assume.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01

/out:assume.exe
assume.obj

C:\temp\code>assume
NoAssumeSwitchStatement: 29.5321ms
  AssumeSwitchStatement: 31.0288ms
```

This is with max optimizations (/Ox)  Note that /O2 was basically identical speedwise.

```
C:\temp\code>cl /Ox /EHsc /Fa assume.cpp
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86

assume.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01
/out:assume.exe
assume.obj

C:\temp\code>assume
NoAssumeSwitchStatement: 1.33492ms
  AssumeSwitchStatement: 0.666948ms
```

This run was to minimize code space

```
C:\temp\code>cl -O1 /EHsc /FAscu assume.cpp
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
assume.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01
/out:assume.exe
assume.obj

C:\temp\code>assume
NoAssumeSwitchStatement: 5.67691ms
  AssumeSwitchStatement: 5.36186ms
```

Note that the output assembly code agrees with what Matthiu M. had to say when speed opts are used.  The switch functions were called in other cases.

Comment: Jim, I was able to reproduce your middle performance gain finding using VS2010. The performance gain does not show up in VS2008. Thanks.

Comment: Additional finding: The __assume(0) switch statement optimization only works with the x86 VS2010 compiler and not the x64 VS2010 compiler.

Comment: @Neil Justice: 5 years ago or so this type of optimization was important to me as I was trying to saturate a gigabit ethernet.  One thing I learned while working on that was that the prefetch  intrinsics, when used correctly would speed things up a crazy amount.  So if you're looking for that type of speedup, look closely at the intrinsics.  I had 2 orders of magnitude speed improvement on a hash function that worked on 128 byte strings from simply getting the prefetch in the right place.  I didn't try x64 or VS 2008 because neither is available to me at this time. :)

Answer (score 10):

Benchmark lies. They rarely measure what you want them to. In this particular case, the methods were probably inlined, and so the `__assume` was just redundant.

As to the actual question, yes it may help. A switch is generally implemented by a jump table, by reducing the size of this table, or removing some entries, the compiler might be able to select better CPU instructions to implement the `switch`.

In your extreme case, it can turn the `switch` into a `if (i == 0) { } else { }` structure, which is usually efficient.

Furthermore, trimming dead branches help keeping code tidy, and less code means a better usage of the CPU instruction cache.

However, those are micro-optimizations, and they rarely pay off: you need a profiler to point them out you, and even them it might be difficult to understand the particular transformation to make (is `__assume` the best ?). This is expert's work.

**EDIT**: In action with LLVM

```
void foo(void);
void bar(void);

void regular(int i) {
  switch(i) {
  case 0: foo(); break;
  case 1: bar(); break;
  }
}

void optimized(int i)  {
  switch(i) {
  case 0: foo(); break;
  case 1: bar(); break;
  default: __builtin_unreachable();
  }
}
```

Note that the only difference is the presence, or absence of the `__builtin_unreachable()` which is similar to MSVC `__assume(0)`.

```
define void @regular(i32 %i) nounwind uwtable {
  switch i32 %i, label %3 [
    i32 0, label %1
    i32 1, label %2
  ]

; <label>:1                                       ; preds = %0
  tail call void @foo() nounwind
  br label %3

; <label>:2                                       ; preds = %0
  tail call void @bar() nounwind
  br label %3

; <label>:3                                       ; preds = %2, %1, %0
  ret void
}

define void @optimized(i32 %i) nounwind uwtable {
  %cond = icmp eq i32 %i, 1
  br i1 %cond, label %2, label %1

; <label>:1                                       ; preds = %0
  tail call void @foo() nounwind
  br label %3

; <label>:2                                       ; preds = %0
  tail call void @bar() nounwind
  br label %3

; <label>:3                                       ; preds = %2, %1
  ret void
}
```

And note here how the `switch` statement in `regular` can be optimized into a simple comparison in `optimized`.

This maps to the following x86 assembly:

```
    .globl  regular                  |      .globl  optimized
    .align  16, 0x90                 |      .align  16, 0x90
    .type   regular,@function        |      .type   optimized,@function
regular:                             |    optimized:
.Ltmp0:                              |    .Ltmp3:
    .cfi_startproc                   |            .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:                              |    # BB#0:
    cmpl    $1, %edi                 |            cmpl    $1, %edi
    je      .LBB0_3                  |            je      .LBB1_2
# BB#1:                              |
    testl    %edi, %edi              |
    jne     .LBB0_4                  |
# BB#2:                              |    # BB#1:
    jmp     foo                      |            jmp     foo
.LBB0_3:                             |    .LBB1_2:
    jmp     bar                      |            jmp     bar
.LBB0_4:                             |
    ret                              |
.Ltmp1:                              |    .Ltmp4:
    .size   regular, .Ltmp1-regular  |      .size   optimized, .Ltmp4-optimized
.Ltmp2:                              |    .Ltmp5:
    .cfi_endproc                     |      .cfi_endproc
.Leh_func_end0:                      |    .Leh_func_end1:
```

Note how, in the second case:

- the code is tighter (less instructions)
- there is a single comparison/jump (cmpl/je) on all paths (and not one path with a single jump and a path with two)

Also note how this is so close that I have no idea how to measure anything else than noise...

On the other hand, semantically it does indicate an intent, though perhaps an `assert` could be better suited for the semantics only.

Comment: Matthieu, speculating about whether or not the compiler performs one optimization or another is all well and good, but can you come up with code and benchmarks that show a use of __assume that benefits performance?

Comment: @NeilJustice: I have added LLVM IR and x86 assembly. I don't have Visual Studio at hand (and don't plan to ever have it again) so I used Clang's `__builtin_unreachable` instead. I have not benchmarked the code, JimR's answer seem pretty exhaustive on that point and... anyway in real world functions it'll probably be drown in the noise.

Comment: Matthieu, I was able to confirm your finding of assembly instruction differences  between __assume(0) and not __assume(0) in assembly output by VS2010. Thanks.